# Is it possible to configure ssh to login with a key if it exists or use a password if it doesn't?

Tags: ssh

I'm trying to configure sshd for our internal network to accept public key authentication if a user has set up their key or ask for password if the user has not, but not both.

So a user should be able to login passwordless if they have their public key configured or be asked for a password if they haven't set up a public key.

Ubuntu 14.04

OpenSSH-server 1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2

Comment: "but not both": Uh, what? This is the default behaviour of SSH on Ubuntu (and on Debian, and on Arch, and on CentOS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In /etc/ssh/sshd_config, you need to have both
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication yes 
set for this user (or all users). 
And of course have a password set, and authorized_keys set for public-key auth.

Comment: Thank you... I have those set, but I just discovered that there was something else wrong. I'm using 'Match' blocks and the general settings overruled those.

Answer (score 0):

When you generate your key by `ssh-keygen` (or other program) you should copy it on server by running

```
ssh-copy-id user@host
```

It will ask for user's password once and then you will be able to login using that key (without password).